# How to detect android app when it detects a wifi

Tags: android, wifi

I want my app to detect the wifi that is connected.

For example, i wanna know how the app can connect to wifi and tell me that it has already been connected.

Comment: you must be find something before posting it,.

Comment: @Marius Per your dupe link, voting to close; thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos actually i found some codes here but I dont have any idea where to put.

Comment: The question is already marked as duplicate, so for your next question, add the code to the question. Surround the code with back ticks or indent it. See the help for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String LOGTAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "WiFi Status Changed");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG,
                        "Wifi is connected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest :

```
    <receiver android:name=".WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: also explain how can we call it.Or it is automatically called.

Comment: Well, its a broadcast receiver so the onReceive method will be automatically called when the WiFi State changes.

Comment: @ShivamVerma hi! thanks for the ans, but i am a noob in making an app, may i know where to put the codes or maybe you can copy and paste the whole coding in a java project?

Comment: Well, just create a new Java file named WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver in the src folder and add the first part of code in it. Add the second part to your android manifest just after the </activity> tag.

Comment: @ShivamVermaisit java package or java class?? Thanks im so sorry i am very new!

Comment: create the java class inside the package.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I'm sorry can I put this code inside protected void onStart()?

Comment: You'll need to go through the basic of android app development and java at the same time. It'll be impossible to help you out to this level. Apologies.

Comment: @heyholetsgobaby So, did anything work ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma it says wifi status change but never print out the `Wifi is connected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));` whenever i change to another ssid